# how can appium which is run on WAN server(cloud server) connect to phone devices which are usb connected to local PC?

Tags: appium, centos8

server environment:
CentOS 8 on remote cloud server
appium 1.21.0 on CentOS 8 
java version "1.8.0_261"
PC environment:
windows 10
phone device connect to windows10 using usb
how can I connect the appium server with PC?

Answer (score 0):

### Architecture:

[image]
Credit Github: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10503

Here we are running scripts from a remote/local Appium server while the devices are connected to another system in the network.

### Setup:

1. Start adb server in the system in which devices are connected:

**Just run the below command in cmd (given adb is available in path)**

```
adb kill-server
adb -a -P 5037 server nodaemon
```

### Appium capabilities:

Now to run appium tests we need to add the below capability:
Try appium inspector from the remote system with below capability (edit all other fields according to your setup except remoteAdbHost,systemport and adbPort)
here remoteadbhost is the remote system which has connected devices change 192.168.0.7 to correct addres, system port is the uiautomator2 server port which is 8021 by default and finally adbport

This will allow you to inspect the remote devices from your local system

```
{
 “platformName”: “Android”,
 “appium:platformVersion”: “11”,
 “appium:deviceName”: “sr”,
 “appium:app”: “C:\\Users\\Downloads\\ApiDemos-debug.apk”,
 “appium:automationName”: “UiAutomator2”,
 "remoteAdbHost":"192:168.0.7",
 "systemPort":8021,
 "adbPort":5037
}
```

**Note**: when using webdriverio 7 add appium: infront of all the capabilities as its the new syntax for w3c.